# The intersection of an ellipsoid and a plane that passes through the X-axis forms a circle.

Tags: geometry

***The Problem:***

We have an ellipsoid:$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1\;\;\;(0<c<a<b)$$
and a plane that passes through the X-axis. The intersection of them forms a circle.

***My Thoughts:***

We set the plane  $ky+mz=0$, since $ 0<c<a<b$，we know that $k \neq 0$ and $m \neq 0$, so we can set the plane  $ty+z=0$.

Eliminate $z$， we have $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{(ty)^2}{c^2}=1$.

***My Problem:***

By eliminating $z$, we only have the parallel projection of the curve on $xOy$. So I can't know whether the curve is a circle or an ellipse.

Please give me some hints to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JeanMarie No, in that case, only the projection on the x-y-plane is a circle, but not the set of points in the given plane.

Comment: @Reinhard Meier. You are prefectly right !

Comment: @Reinhard Meier. Yeah, and this is what I am curious about the problem.

Comment: I think there is no solution. The intersection is an ellipse with a semi-major axis of length $a$ and a semi-minor axis of length $\in[c,b]$ which is strictly smaller than $a$.

Comment: @Rienhard Meier. Ok, and I can change $a>b>c>0$ to $0<c<a<b$, so we have the solution. But what I want to know is how to solve the problem like this?

Comment: What exactly is meant by "a plane, that passes through the $x-$ axis? My naive, first understanding is any plane, which has non empty intersection with the $x$-axis.

Comment: @Thomas. It means $x-axis \subset \pi$.

Comment: @Jean Marie. Please look at the comments below your answer.

Comment: To clarify: Was the question to show that there _exists_ such a plane which fulfills these conditions?

Comment: This is horribly stated. As It stands, we are asked to prove that the intersection is a circle *for every* plane containing the $x$-axis; what is intended is that it be true *for some* such plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

We assume that :

$$0<c<\color{red}{a}<b\tag{1}$$

which is equivalent to :

$$\frac{1}{b}<\frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{c} \ \iff \ \frac{1}{b^2}<\frac{1}{a^2}<\frac{1}{c^2}\tag{1'}$$

Let us consider a  $\theta$ rotation around $x$ axis, inducing the following change of coordinates (please note that, as usual, the old coordinates are expressed with respect to the new ones) :

$$\begin{cases}x&=& \ \ \ x'\\
y&=& \ \ \ y' \cos \theta + z' \sin \theta \\z&=&-y' \sin \theta + z' \cos \theta\end{cases}$$

Plugging these expressions into the equation of the ellipsoid gives :

$$\frac{x'^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y' \cos \theta + z' \sin \theta)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(-y' \sin \theta + z' \cos \theta)^2}{c^2}=1\tag{2}$$

A cross section by, say, plane $y'=0$ gives

$$\frac{x'^2}{a^2}+z'^2 \left(\frac{ \sin (\theta)^2}{b^2}+\frac{ (\cos \theta)^2}{c^2}\right)=1\tag{3}$$

The condition for (3) to be the equation of a circle is that the coefficients of $x'^2$ and $z'^2$ are the same :

$$\frac{1}{a^2}=\frac{\sin (\theta)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(\cos \theta)^2}{c^2},\tag{4}$$

which has the form :

$$\frac{1}{a^2}=k\frac{1}{b^2}+(1-k)\frac{1}{c^2}.\tag{4'}$$

Relationship (4') can be fulfilled because, according to (1'), it is a barycentric combination of the extreme values :

$$\frac{1}{a^2} \in \left[\frac{1}{b^2} \ , \ \frac{1}{c^2}\right]$$

meaning that a certain (unique) value of $\theta \in [0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}]$ exists fulfilling (4).

---

If, on the contrary, we have, instead of (1) :

$$\text{- either} \ \ \ \color{red}{a}<c<b \ \iff \ \frac{1}{b^2}<\frac{1}{c^2}<\frac{1}{a^2}$$

$$\text{- or      } \ \ \ c<b<\color{red}{a} \ \iff \ \frac{1}{a^2}<\frac{1}{b^2}<\frac{1}{c^2},$$

equation (3) cannot be fulfilled because, in both cases  $\frac{1}{a^2}$ is outside segment $\left[\frac{1}{b^2} \ , \ \frac{1}{c^2}\right].$

Comment: "a plane that passes through the X-axis" means the X-axis is a subset to the plane.

Comment: And the details of the problem are $0<c<a<b$ and the X-axis is a subset to the plane.

Comment: In my condition ($ 0<c<a<b$ and the X-axis is a subset to the plane). I can rotate the ellipsoid around $x$ axis and use the plane $y'Ox'$ to cross the ellipsoid.

Comment: In your solution, you rotate the ellipsoid around $z$
 axis and use the plane $y′Oz′$
(or plane $x'Oz'$, because it's the same to fixing the ellipsoid and rotating the plane $xOz$ or any other plane "passing through the $z$axis" ) to cross the ellipsoid.

Comment: I have completely re-written my answer to be in conformity with the assumptions, showing that in fact there is a solution with the given conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You were closer to a solution that you recognized.

Starting from your equation,

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{(ty)^2}{c^2}=1, $$

if you knew the value of $t$ then you would have the equation of an ellipse in the $x,y$ plane, which as you pointed out is of little value to you; but in fact you don't even have the value of $t$ yet. This is the wrong way to think about this equation.

Instead of looking at the plot of $x$ and $y$ in a plane, let's again consider the intersection of the plane $ty+z=0$ with the ellipsoid.
We know that for any value of $t$ the intersection is an ellipse, and one semiaxis of the ellipse is represented by the segment from $(0,0,0)$ to $(a,0,0)$,
of length $a.$
The other semiaxis of the ellipse is represented by a segment from $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,y_0,ty_0)$ for a suitable value of $y_0.$
The length of that segment needs to be $a$ in order for the ellipse to be a circle.
Hence we can write
$$ y_0^2 + (ty_0)^2 = a^2. $$

But since $(0,y_0,ty_0)$ is on the ellipsoid, we also have

$$ \frac{y_0^2}{b^2}+\frac{(ty_0)^2}{c^2}=1. $$

Now you have two independent equations in two unknowns and can solve for $t.$